# Updrade to Windows 10 34 bit

Tags: premiere, video-editor, software-recommendation, setup

I want to upgrade **Windows 10 32 bit** TO **Windows 10 64 bit** for install Premier Pro CS6 .
How do I upgrade that OS ?

Comment: Off-topic here; belongs on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off topic but ill chuck in some pointers

1: Backup ALL your data

2: Make sure all your Data is backed up and unplug the external device

3: Reload Windows 10 x64 from the install disk or USB

4: install all your apps again

5: put your data back

6: start editing on your new Windows 10 x64 system